# Number of days between two dates

Tags: c#, date

I have two dates:

Jun 26 2012 12:13AM and Jul 31 2012 12:54PM

I need to compare this two dates and extract Number of days(difference) between them

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Use [TimeSpan](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.aspx)

```
TimeSpan difference = dateTime1 - dateTime2;
```

`difference.TotalDays` will give you number of days

```
var days = difference.TotalDays;
```

Comment: How to get the current date in this format "Jun 26 2012 12:13AM". I need to get the current date in this format

Comment: Use `DateTime.Now.ToString("MMM dd yyyy hh:mmtt");`